# Multiplying certain rows in a matrix with a constant

Tags: r, matrix, vector, constants, multiplication

I have a vector with positions of rows that i need to multiply with the constant 5, i however can't really find a practical way of doing this. My code looks like this so far:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix( rnorm(200*2, mean=0, sd=1), 200,2)
eucl <- sqrt((X[,1] - X[,2])^2)
pos <- which(eucl > 1),
```

pos is my vector with positions, these are the positions of the rows in my matrix, that i need to multiply

Comment: You need `X[pos,] <- X[pos,] * 5`

Comment: I think that might have done the trick, thank you so much :D !